# how to properly convert byte array in java to char pointer in jni

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am new to C/C++, so I don't know how to properly convert a byte array in Java to a char array in JNI.

For example, I have an `inputString` containing `"Hello world!"`, I use this to get the byte array:

```java
byte[] data = inputString.getBytes();
```

Then in the JNI layer, I use:

```cpp
jbyte *array = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data, &isCopy);
argv[1] = (char *)array;
```

Then when I print the `argv[1]`, it is `"Hello world!ZE"`.

Why is there extra characters `"ZE"` here?

Would anyone explain this, and provide me the right solution to convert `byte[]` to `char*` pointer? I need the `char*` pointer because the interface I am given is `char*` pointer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `byte[]` array is not null-terminated (does not end with a `0x00` byte), but you are clearly treating it as if it were. When printing the bytes, the "extra" characters are random values coming from surrounding memory when the print accesses beyond the bounds of the array, which is *undefined behavior*.

Use `(*env)->GetArrayLength()` to find out how many bytes are actually in the array, and then don't access more bytes than that, eg:

```c
jint len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, data);
jbyte *array = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, data, &isCopy);
argv[1] = (char*) array;
...
printf("%.*s", len, argv[1]);
...
(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, data, array, JNI_ABORT);
```

If you really need a null-terminated string (or just need to hold on to the data longer than the Java `byte[]` array will exist), you will have to allocate your own `char[]` buffer with extra room for a terminator, and then copy the `byte[]` array data into that buffer, eg:

```c
jint len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, data);

jbyte *array = malloc(len + 1);
if (array) {
    (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, data, 0, len, array);
    array[len] = 0x00;
}

argv[1] = (char*) array;
...
printf("%s", argv[1]);
...
free(argv[1]);
```

Comment: I used this function (*env)->GetArrayLength(), it showed the length is 12 which is correct. So I still don't know why there is extra "ZE"

Comment: I already told you why - you are treating the `char*` as a **null-terminated** string, but the `byte[]` data IS NOT null-terminated!

Comment: o right, I should read your comment carefully. Thank you.